# Integration of Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM) with React Native (iOS and Android)

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-fcm

I am new to React-native and trying to implement push notifications with Google's Firebase cloud messaging library (iOS and Android). I have gone through many articles but none of them explain things as far as a beginner is concerned. Can anyone suggest some good documentation that addresses all the points regarding the setup and the use from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the documentation of `react-native-fcm` and `react-native-firebase`